# Find the list of defined sammy.js routes

Tags: javascript, routes, sammy.js

[Sammy.js](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/) is a controller library in javascript. But sometimes we have a 404 because our route doesn't seems to be valid to sammy.

How to know which route are defined by Sammy.js in a page ?

Something like the ruby on rails' `rake routes`.

Like answers we can search on app.routes. So I have something like in coffee script :

```
jQuery.each app.routes, (r) ->
  console.log(JSON.stringify(r))
  jQuery.each app.routes[r], (u) ->
    console.log(JSON.stringify(u))
```

or in JS

```
jQuery.each(app.routes, function(r) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
  return jQuery.each(app.routes[r], function(u) {
    return console.log(JSON.stringify(u));
  });
});
```

But it's not output the good routes I have in output :

```
"get"
0
1
"post"
0
1
2
etc...
```

So which code to do ?

Comment: the route is the one i say! ;) (i didn't know i was almost a controller library ;) )

Comment: yes there are no answer before this one about this library. So I link it in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that

```
var app = $.sammy.apps['body'];

jQuery.each(app.routes, function(verb, routes) {
  jQuery.each(routes, function(i, route) {
    console.log(route.verb, route.path);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

RTC: routes are added to **app.routes**, just write an accessor which return an iterator on it.

Comment: You right, but it's more complicated like that because the routes is an Hash with key verb and value URL